# what does the second address refer to in this link

Tags: contract-development

What does the second address refer to in this link?

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2&address=0x4e83362442b8d1bec281594cea3050c8eb01311c&offset=10000000000&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

Answer (score 1):

Probably off topic...

Just breaking down the link into its components:

- Using the EtherScan API: `https://api.etherscan.io/api?`
- ...specifically the [accounts](https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts) part of the API: `module=account`
- ...looking at token transactions: `&action=tokentx`
- ...involving a particular token contract: `&contractaddress=0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2`
- ...to or from a particular (externally owned) account: `&address=0x4e83362442b8d1bec281594cea3050c8eb01311c`
- ...and returning a maximum of 10000000000 records: `&offset=10000000000`
- ...sorted in order of ascending block number: `&sort=asc`
- (Using your API key, if you have one: `&apikey=YourApiKeyToken`)

---

So it's showing details of token transfer events involving a particular user's account. (Which is the address you're asking about.) Note that there are both *from* and *to* listings for that address.

Comment: ok, so that code was from a website I downloaded to go through and try to figure how everything works together. I put in the ropsten contract address for a simple token I created and then put in for the second address the metamask account address I created the token from. Is that correct? It doesn't work when I do preview from Dreamweaver

Comment: the link was from the .js file attached to the website

Comment: If you're on Ropsten, you'll need to use the Ropsten version of the API. So the link would start with `https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io`...

Comment: And you'll need to actually perform a token transfer transaction from/to the address you've created in Metamask (ensuring it's connected to Ropsten) for anything to show up.